# Replicate behaviour of credit card expiry date field

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, html-input

I am trying to replicate the behaviour of the **CC exp date** **MM/YY format** field as seen on [Digital Ocean](https://cloud.digitalocean.com/settings/billing) [you need to be logged in to see the page and payment form]

It works like this:
1. If I press <kbd>0</kbd> or <kbd>1</kbd>, it waits for further input
2. If I press anything between <kbd>2</kbd> - <kbd>9</kbd>, it transforms to `02/`, `09/`, etc and then waits for further input for **YY**

The user can press `01/` and I must handle that

The user can press `1/` and I must handle that as well

The checks on DO are not very strict and allow inputs like `15/34` or copy pasting illegal values which are handled separately.

I tried to add a `oninput` event listener that checks for input values and modifies if the value is a number greater than 2. But that does not appear very elegant. I have to check the input field value after every keypress and it looks like a mess.

**EDIT**
After thinking over it a lot I was finally able to recreate much of the intended functionality but it still not perfect.

```js
jQuery('body').on('keyup', '.paymentDate', function(e){
console.log($(this).val());

var val = $(this).val();
if(!isNaN(val)) {
    if(val > 1 && val < 10 && val.length == 1) {
        temp_val = "0" + val + "/";
        $(this).val(temp_val);
    }
    else if (val >= 1 && val < 10 && val.length == 2 && e.keyCode != 8) {
        temp_val = val + "/";
        $(this).val(temp_val);            
    }
    else if(val > 9 && val.length == 2 && e.keyCode != 8) {
        temp_val = val + "/";
        $(this).val(temp_val);
    }
}
else {
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="paymentDate" class="paymentDate">
```

[Find Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6u2rybed/2/)

Is there a smarter way or a plugin that can handle this efficiently?

Comment: So where is the mystery code?

Comment: @RobG added a fiddle

Comment: Far better to post the code here, where it will remain for as long as the question does. External links break. You can post [*runnable code snippets*](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) directly into your question.

Comment: The problem with modifying user  input as they are typing is that it confuses users, I'd seriously recommend not doing it. It may seem cool, but just increases frustration.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the question last `if else` statement. This should work:

```
else if(val > 9 && val.length == 2 && e.keyCode != 8) {
  if (val > 12) {
    temp_val = "0" + val[0] + "/" + val[1];
    $(this).val(temp_val);
  } else {
    temp_val = val + "/";
      $(this).val(temp_val);
  }
}
```